# PHP Time() to Google Calendar Dates time format

Tags: php, datetime, time, google-calendar-api

I have PHP times for the start and end times of an event.  This is a simple `<?php time(); ?>` for some future date's start and end time.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to take either the numerical format (PHP time()) or taking some string value representing that time (I could do a `strtotime($sometimevalue);`) and turn it into the required Google Calendar time format.

Enough talking - here is an example of the time format:

```
20150107T003000Z/20150107T023000Z
```

This equates to January 6th, 2015 at 5:30 PM to January 6th, 2015 at 7:30PM.

So can someone explain to me how to translate a `time()` to this format?

Comment: The things that confuse me are, the event is on Jan 6th, yet the time format says '20150107T'.  I would think it would be `20150106T`  Also, the time afterwords being `003000Z` for 5:30 pm to `023000Z` for 7:30 pm.  Thats just hard for me to tell where these numbers are being generated from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working solution taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
Credit goes to Boris Korobkov.

```
// boris at psyonline dot ru 14-Jun-2007 03:05

<?php

/**
 * Get date in RFC3339
 * For example used in XML/Atom
 *
 * @param integer $timestamp
 * @return string date in RFC3339
 * @author Boris Korobkov
 */
function date3339($timestamp=0) {

    if (!$timestamp) {
        $timestamp = time();
    }
    $date = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $timestamp);

    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/^([\-+])(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', date('O', $timestamp), $matches)) {
        $date .= $matches[1].$matches[2].':'.$matches[3];
    } else {
        $date .= 'Z';
    }
    return $date;
}

?>
```

Background:
  From 
    http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-xpath/
  I saw
    "The published and updated elements use the RFC 3339 time-stamp format. "

And figured I ought google "rfc3339 PHP" to find a function that implements this format

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date = date("Ymd\THis\Z");
```

The first line sets the default timezone to use to be UTC (this is the "Z" at the end of the formatted time: `Z = "Zulu Time"`). I did this since I don't know if Google is expecting a UTC time or not. If you can use other timezones, then you can use [one of the other timezone formats available](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

In the next line, I use `date` to format the current Unix timestamp (when no timestamp is passed to `date` it defaults to the current time - i.e. `time()`). I'll break it apart for you:

- `Y` - The four-digit year
- `m` - The two-digit (including leading zero, if necessary) month
- `d` - The two-digit (including leading zero, if necessary) day of the month
- `\T` - The literal character `T`, which is a delimiter identifying that the time portion of the date is beginning. The slash is to escape the T, as it is otherwise used to display the timezone abbreviation (e.g. "PST")
- `H` - The two-digit (including leading zero, if necessary) hour
- `i` - The two-digit (including leading zero, if necessary) minute
- `s` - The two-digit (including leading zero, if necessary) second
- `\Z` - The literal character `Z`, indicating zulu time as discussed above. The slash is to escape the T, as it is otherwise used to display the timezone in seconds from UTC.

For reference, and to be sure I interpreted the question accurately, this code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date("Ymd\THis\Z", time());
```

Currently displays this result:

```
20110415T014623Z
```

I should note that you could also use `gmdate()` in place of `date()` and eliminate the need for the `date_default_timezone_set()` call, since `gmdate()` returns the result in GMT. I only hesitate to mention this because I've never been 100% clear on the difference, if any, between GMT and UTC, especially with other timezones/periods like BST (British Summer Time) and how they alter GMT, if at all. If someone could clarify this in the comments, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: You can leave out the call to `time()` there.

Comment: @deceze - You're absolutely right. If you leave out the second parameter, `date` defaults to the current date/time. I was testing with a string value there, and I guess I had a brainfart when I changed it. Thanks, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hmm.  I like this.  I am currently using a javascript implementation that i found on google.  I could try this out to verify that it works :)

Comment: Well i am going to verify this works now... ill let you know!

Comment: Doesn't work with new versions of PHP (7+). This code will print nothing: `'$STARTDATETIME  = "Nov 3, 2019 15:30";  echo date("Ymd\THis\Z", strtotime($STARTDATETIME);`

Answer (score 3):

It's little bit old but Google expects to get time in a ISO 8601. Example :

```
$objDateTime = new DateTime('NOW');
$isoDate = $objDateTime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

[SOURCE](https://developers.google.com/schemas/formats/datetime-formatting)

Comment: Thankfully I have moved on from programming php :) . but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I use:

```
$postBody = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
.......
    'start' => array(
            'dateTime' => date_format($event_Start_datetime,'c');
........ 

//'c' - formats DateTime object as needed for Google Calendar
```